# libevent2 http not detecting client network broken

Tags: libevent

I am not pasting the source code here, if any one whats to reproduce the problem, download the code from [this github project](https://github.com/ideawu/icomet):

It is a Comet server, the server use libevent-2.0.21-stable http.

To reproduce the problem:

1. start the icomet-server from machine S
2. run `curl http://ip:8100/stream` from another machine C, the server S will show message that C has connected
3. if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to terminate curl, the server knows that C is disconnected as expected.
4. if I pull out the network line from machine C(a physical network broken), the server will NOT know that C is disconnected, which it SHOULD know!

I will askany one who is familiar with libevent, how to make libevent 2 to detecting client network broken?

Answer (score 1):

When the physical network link is interrupted, you won't always get a packet back to tell you that you lost the connection. If you want to find out about a disconnection, send a ping (a request that just asks for a no-op reply) periodically, and if the reply doesn't come within some reasonable timeout, assume something went wrong. Or just disconnect the client if they're idle for long enough.

When you did that Ctrl-C, the OS that the other end was running on was still working, and so it was able to generate a TCP RST packet to inform your server that the client has gone away. But when you break that physical link, the client is no longer capable of sending that cry for help. Something else has to infer that the client went away.

Now, if you try to send the client some data, the server kernel will notice (sooner or later) that the client is not replying to its messages. At this point you'll see the disconnect - but it may take several minutes for this to happen. If you're *not* sending any data, then it'll stay open until either you disconnect it, or the kernel attempts a TCP keepalive (a low-level way of the kernel asking "Hey, I haven't heard from you for a while, are you still there?") potentially hours later (or it might not even do a keepalive at all for you, depending on how things are configured).

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned if the server send the client some data, it will discover the client's disconnect - "but it may take several minutes for this to happen". This is a acceptable method and I am able to implement, but another question - how to shorten the time(to 3 seconds for instance)? Is there any libevent configuration about this?

Comment: This is governed by TCP retransmit timeouts, and you can't really shorten it much, without making the network seriously unreliable. With such a configuration, multiple retransmits would need to happen within those 3 seconds, which could create a lot of load on a network that's dropping packets because it's overloaded. Additionally, several-second network drops are very common (particularly for mobile devices), so you may not want to respond so quickly anyway.